# Refresh div content after click link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Prestashop v1.6 default-bootstrap theme, product-list.tpl file.

I have a button add to cart and div with some smarty code:

```
<a class="ajax_add_to_cart_button" href="....">

<div id="div1">{if $added}Added{else}not added{/if}</div>
```

Now when I click to link I want to only refresh div content.

I already try some code finding in stack but my knowledge is still not enought.

What I try and it is not work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ajax_add_to_cart_button', function() {
    $("#div1").load()       /*also $("#div1").load("#div1")*/
});
```

and:

```
$("#div1").load(location.href + " #div1");
```

and few more.

EDIT, also this is not work for me:

```
$(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.ajax_add_to_cart_button', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#div1").load($(this).attr("href")); /*and this:  $("#div1").load($(this).attr("href #div1"));*/
return false
});
});
```

**EDIT2:** When I try this code is half working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".ajax_add_to_cart_button").click(function(){
$("#div1").html("result reloaded successfully");
});
});
```

why half? Because text is display but only in first product, and it is no matter which one product I click, and also I try switch `html()` to `load()` or `refresh()` but then is not working.

**EDIT3**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var productid = "{product.id_product}"
$(".ajax_add_to_cart_button").click(function(){
$("#div1" + productid).html("result reloaded successfully");
});
});


<div id="div1{product.id_product}">{if $added}Added{else}not added{/if}</div>
```

It is display info in all product, all container in product have now different id.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand well what do you want to do, because you say only for first product... It's unclear, can you explain me better?

Comment: I have a list of product, every product have this filed `#div1`, when I add third product to cart this message from `html()` should show on third product but it is show always on first product.

Comment: Mmm... I see... I guess your problem is that you use the same id for all the products. The DOM 'should' have a unique ID for one element, try another way, maybe a simple class as a selector, you couldn't use the same id for all that elements :)

Comment: I tried to ia another way, but still solution from EDIT2 is not enough becouse it is use html() but I want to refresh div content not display custom code. I make some changes in code now info from html() is display in all products.

Comment: But what do you mean 'refresh div content'? Refresh with other content?

Answer (score 1):

try following and check if it works..

```
$(function(){
 $(document).on('click', '.ajax_add_to_cart_button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#one").load($(this).attr("href"));
    return false.
});

});
```

I noticed you have wrong class in your selector. please check that too.

Comment: Thanks but this is not work for me, and you have dot after false, I also edit my first post with what I try. After add your solution in div is loaded all site content and product didn't go to cart.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... I see... I guess your problem is that you use the same id for all the products. The DOM 'should' have a unique ID for one element, try another way, maybe a simple class as a selector, you couldn't use the same id for all that elements :)

For example (I'm assuming that your div have `mybeautifuldiv` class):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ajax_add_to_cart_button").click(function(){
        $(".mybeautifuldiv").html("result reloaded successfully");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this when there is a list of products (category page etc.) then you need to target a proper div. And you might not want to use id but class in your div.

```
<div class="my-custom-div">{if $added}Added{else}not added{/if}</div>
```

Is this div inside 'add to cart' anchor?
If it is then you need to target it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ajax_add_to_cart_button").click(function() {
        $(this).find('.my-custom-div').html('Content updated!');
    });
});
```

If it is not then you can traverse to parent div of product and find your custom div inside it. For example in a category page of a default prestashop theme:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ajax_add_to_cart_button").click(function() {           
        $(this).closest('.product-container').find('.my-custom-div').html('Content updated!');
    });
});
```